# What could be the cause of a "connection reset" error in the browser?

Tags: networking, connection, lamp

One of our clients host our cms on his in-house server, the employees are connected to the server, and also we can connect to the server, through a VPN, we are in a different country. The internet connection at the client's data center is fast, faster than ours.

If we generate the report, it takes 8 minutes to be done and everything works well. If the client's employees try to do the same, it takes 15 minutes, and then the browser says "connection reset", and they're never able to successfully generate it.

Both parties are using the latest google chrome, the client's employees are saying that there is no firewall running on their PC. There's a firewall running on the server, but both parties are connected to the same server, and the same MYSQL database, it takes significantly less time to do the task from our end and doesn't throw an error.

Also, no other client is having the same problem. It's a LAMP installation on centos 6.5, can this issue be debugged?

Comment: Are they going through an HTTP proxy?

Comment: @slhck, did not ask but most likely yes, they are employees at a huge datacenter after all.

Comment: I guess it depends on how the report is generated. Do you click on a button, and a website loads, and at some point, it downloads the file? Or is there something interactive/asynchronous happening on the website? Perhaps you can show a screenshot of the "Network" tab of Chrome while generating the report, optionally blanking some confidential info.

Comment: The "connection reset" might be caused by the server being configured to disconnect idle connections after (perhaps) 10 minutes. So you might only have one basic problem to solve, which is the slower processing of the request. I suggest to compare the priority level of the process when run in the two cases.